# Can I make php automatically escape HTML chars when using <?= ?>?

Tags: php, html, escaping

I am using unescaped data for example `some string " <>> ' blah`.

This causes trouble when I do this:

```php
<input value="<?= $my_string ?>">
```

Which results in:

```html
<input value="some string " <>> ' blah">
```

Is there a way to tell php to call `htmlspecialchars` on everything before printing it to the html document using `<?= ?>` so I don't have to call it manually every time?

Comment: No, you cant. You can write your own print function which doesnt have a name as long as `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: PHP can't do it for you, but you can use a templating engine that has that functionality it, like [twig](https://twig.symfony.com/). However, that would then only apply to outputs in templates, not on any PHP echo's in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible.
But you could make a shortcut method that. For example like this:

```
function h($string){
     return htmlspecialchars($string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do on my website is that I have a premade function that I call whenever I am echo'ing something on either a profile or anywhere.

It looks like this:

```
function text_convert($txt){
     return htmlspecialchars($txt);
}
```

Then I can simply run it like this: `echo text_convert($string);`

Comment: but I was wondering if it was possible to do it automatically before printing it out without calling any function

Comment: @swiftlynx No, this isn't possible.

Comment: This doesn't actually address the OP's question at all.

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of ways of dealing with it, just using single quotes in the HTML is the quickest and dirtiest:

```
<input value='<?= $my_string ?>'>
```

Comment: But this only works for the example string provided by me. The data I'm talking about could contain single quotes as well.

Comment: This doesn't actually address the OP's question at all.